# Angular 11 any/undefined types warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, strict

I upgraded my app from Angular v10 to v11 and now I get multiple errors and warnings because some (maybe all) fields can be undefined in a time:

for example:

```
const savedToken = new Token(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(AuthInterceptor.tokenKey)));
```

must become:

```
const savedToken = new Token(JSON.parse(<string>localStorage.getItem(AuthInterceptor.tokenKey)));
```

warning:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. 
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string' 
// I know the localStorage value can be null in this case.
```

another example:

```
public user$: Observable<User>;
// Property 'user$' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

because the `user$` is initialized in `ngOnInit()` as `this.user$ = this.store.pipe()...`

How did you solve it?

Even if I deactivate `strict` from `angular.json`, the result is same:

```
"@schematics/angular:application": {
    "strict": false
}
```

I really need to update all my app code line by line to angular 11? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by TypeScript's Strict Class Initialization.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization

### Solution 1

Utilize the `prop!: Type` syntax as indicated by the TypeScript documentation to indicate to the compiler that we are aware that the prop has not been initialized and we will handle it later.

```js
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent {
 @Input() inputExampleProp!: string; // ! indicates that we know the variable may be undefined
}
```

### Alternate Solution

If you do not care about strict class initialization, you can disable the feature completely in your `tsconfig.json` by adding a flag to your compiler options

```json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

**Note:** You may have to restart your IDE for the compilerOptions to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With strictPropertyInitialization: false still not working (even restarting the IDE). I need to use prop!: Type for each declaration. even where I use form fields, I need to use "?" to check if it exists: const username = this.registerForm.get('userName')?.value;

Comment: alternate solution solve my life. Hint: is on "compilerOptions", not on "AngularComiplerOptions"

Comment: You dont have to restart WebStorm to notice the change in tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the second solution is not working for me, the first one yes

Answer (score 0):

in ts.config file you just have to change strict:"true" to strict:"false"

"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": false,

THEN IF IT STILL SHOWS ERROR RESTART VISUAL STUDIO CODE IDE!!!